# Can I reference the font-face in a separate 3rd party CSS file?

Tags: unicode, font-awesome

We're including font awesome using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This HTML is being output on the front end.

In a separate CSS file we have the rule:

```
.media-vid:before {
    content: '\f167';
    font-family: FontAwesome; 
}
```

however, the front end displays a hollow square where the icon should be.

[image]

In our own CSS file, can I reference the `font-face` that is defined in a separate 3rd party CSS file?

Help appreciated.

Comment: is that youtube icon ?

Comment: It shoud be. \f167 https://fontawesome.com/icons/youtube?style=brands&from=io

Comment: yes @benjaminc it is

Comment: Isn't that what I am using @HonsaStunna ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new font awesome has a new font name. Try using

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
```

It is working in my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/honsa/akexzjg8/7/

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you Honsa. I guess the answer is yes, you can make the reference, you just need to get the right font. Cheers,